# What is the max length of a share path in windows?

Tags: c#, windows

As I read in the MSDN site, for example, the maximum path on drive D is "D:\some 256-character path string" where "" represents the invisible terminating null character for the current system codepage.

But when I was created a share with a long path (more than 100 symbols) they trim it to 100 symbols.
So, where I can find the information about the max share path in windows 7, for example?

Comment: Umm... sounds like it's 100 in your case? What are you actually trying to ask here?

Comment: How did you create the share? The limitation could come from other places not the actual share path.

Comment: @Luaan I need a general case

Comment: The Sharename (alone) max size that Windows 7 allows me to set (from cmd or UI) is 80 chars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See MSDN documentation at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc249520.aspx, 0x104 = 260 characters. Not a lot...

On file shares, NTFS supports file paths of up to 32K characters but for some reason you need to specify, when saving, that you want to use this feature by prefixing your path name with `\\?\`, for instance `\\?\D:\Shared\VeryLongPath`.

Comment: but this is a local path